# Couldn't locate mysql.sock file after installation

Tags: mysql

Installed Mysql server in a fresh linux machine , after trying to run the command mysql command i am getting below error

```
error 2002 (hy000): can't connect to local mysql server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I checked internet , and as per my understanding this .sock file will create only when the server starts , but for me before starting the mysql server itself i am getting this error, someone pls help me out to resolve this issue.